# Convert active record result into Json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have below output from active record query

```
[{"image_id"=>1, "image_name"=> "image1", action_type"=>"Call", "count"=>2}, 
`{"image_id"=>1, "image_name"=> "image1","action_type"=>"sms", "count"=>1},  
 {"image_id"=>2, "image_name"=> "image2","action_type"=>"sms", "count"=>1} ]`
```

Now I want this to be converted into Json object like below

```
{ "1": {  "counts": { "call": 2,  "sms": 1 } , "title":'image1' },  
  "2": { "counts":  {"sms": 1} , 'title':'image2'}}
```

Comment: There's no built in way. Also, you ever heard of db normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code.

```
@xx = [{"image_id"=>1, "image_name"=>"image1", "action_type"=>"Call", "count"=>2}, {"image_id"=>1, "image_name"=>"image1", "action_type"=>"sms", "count"=>1}, {"image_id"=>1, "image_name"=>"image1", "action_type"=>"sms", "count"=>1}]
@arr = []

@xx.each_with_index do |x, i|
    @arr << {(i+1).to_s.to_sym => {"counts" => {x["action_type"].to_sym => x["count"]}}}
end

respond_to do |f|
    f.json {render :json => @arr}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two popular libraries that are both very helpful:

- [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)
- [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

I prefer active_model_serializers, personally. Many disagree.